# PHP: Passing variables for mysql query without enclosing them in " or '

Tags: php, mysql

There's an open source application that does queries like so:

```
$db->query('SELECT item FROM table WHERE something='.$something);
```

This works fine, mysql runs the query however if I use exactly the same method I get an error, mysql is seeing it as "something = (value of $something)" and it's (rightly) complaining that (value of $something) is not a row. These applications both run on the same server and I've rooted through their code for hours but I cannot work out what is causing it.

```
$db->query('SELECT item FROM table WHERE something='.$something);
```

works in their application but fails in mine. Do I need to do something with the string I'm passing? I have no problem enclosing the variables properly, like:

```
$db->query('SELECT item FROM table WHERE something="'.$something.'"');
```

but I'd like to know what causes the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL needs the string to be enclosed. The only thing I can think is that $something is an integer or a float.

Comment: Aha! I think you might be right. How did I miss that, I can't believe it. Silly me... Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass numbers without quotes

```
SELECT ... WHERE id=5
```

but you have to mark string literals as such with quotes

```
SELECT ... WHERE id='abc'
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

1. The code is bad bad bad if $something comes from the user/browser. That's call sql_injection error
2. Send us the exact code statement and sql log so we can see what is happening

Comment: of course the data has been sanitized before hand! It was just a silly mistake on my part, I'd overlooked the fact that numbers and strings are treated differently by mysql, mysql will take and handle numbers fine w/out being enclosed, but if I don't enclose a string it can't handle it. Thanks!

Comment: right, that's a really really bad practice. avoid this way of building sql queries and start using prepared statements: http://devzone.zend.com/article/686#Heading10, http://www.petefreitag.com/item/356.cfm

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$db->query('SELECT item FROM table WHERE something={$something}');
```

This will work

Comment: In my opinion a comment would be nice if someone votes down, because there is a big learning process if someone says your faults. So that i can learn from my Faults ;-)

Comment: I imagine you were voted down because braces {} are used to wrap complex variables such as class vars or array items in strings - they won't enclose the outputted variable though.